# my vb.net database isn't saving data

Tags: vb.net

first I'm using visual studio 2010. let's get into the problem:
simply as the question, I'm trying to insert data into my student table and it's not.

this is a picture of my database [mydatabse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdJoM.png)
this is a picture of my data source[my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICKyj.png)
this is the code for my add button:

```
  If Not Tbl_StudentsTableAdapter.student_adddd(txtStundent.Text, 
     txtAddress.Text, txtDate.Value.Date) = Nothing Then

        Me.Validate()
        Me.Tbl_StudentsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Studentdata)

    End If

End Sub
```

when I hit this button it works perfectly to the data grid that on the form, but when I close the application everything goes back as it was.

Comment: The tablea dapter manager `. UpdateAll` returns the number of rows that were updated. Create an integer and set it to the returned value. See how many rows were affected.

Comment: Remember that in Debug Mode the dara is only temporary since it wil regenerate some data. To check if after form close the data is still there try to complie and generate and launch the application directly.

Comment: Your source database is in the project folder, along with all the other source files. By default, that source database is copied to the output folder, along with all the other output files (e.g. the EXE) and it's that copy that your application connects to. Because it's copied on every build, any changes you make will be lost any time you make a code change and run the app again. If you change the `Copy To Output Directory` property of the database to `Copy If Newer` then the source database will only be copied if you make changes to it, rather than to any source file.

Comment: well, i just want to clear one thing. I have tried this on another PC and the same problem still exists. when I do add the students from data source and keep the Studentbidnignavigator, so when I run the application and add more students then hit the save button all good for now, but going back to database and ask it to execute queries meaning to find all the students i added in the form but too bad i lose all the data in both places.